# Is it acceptable to cut studs to install an electrical panel?

Tags: studs, electrical-panel

Our electrician cut out 2 by 4's to install an electrical panel between them.  He put a screw through the box into the cut end of the 2 by 4 in only three places.  I don't believe it's a load bearing wall, but is this right?

Comment: Can you [post a photo](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33)?

Comment: Yes photo needed.  The way this is described seems really half-assed.  I don't know if my local inspectors would OK it as I would never not frame a panel basically like a window.

Comment: I would agree with the "half-assed" part. The electrical code rquires work to be done in a "neat and workmanlike manner". This doen't sound like it lives up to that requirement.

Answer (score 4):

It's not likely a problem. However, it would be preferable to at least box the area with a flat header and sill. This will help reduce movement that could crack drywall joints later, and will keep the drywall more stable around the box.